# Jest performance issues

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have few Jest test for React component with Enzyme in Typescript.
The performance of Jest seems to be very very poor. Here is a screenshot of some test cases.
The total amount of time for each test in a file is <1sec, but the total runtime is **>400sec for a file** - this is insane! We have some files and the total test time can take **>2hours**!

This times are little bit faster when we run this again, but the problem is that CI takes *a lot of time*.

Here are the Jest configuration files. Any idea how to make this reasonable?

[image]

This is the `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.jsx?$": "ts-jest",
        "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest",
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/"],
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/Tests/config/setupTest.js"],
    testRegex: "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
    moduleDirectories: [
        "node_modules",
        "<rootDir>"
    ],
    modulePathIgnorePatterns: [
        "<rootDir>/bin",
        "<rootDir>/obj"
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "<rootDir>/Tests/config/mocks/styleMock.js",
        "\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg)$": "<rootDir>/Tests/config/mocks/fileMock.js"
    }
};
```

This is the `setupTest.js`

```
// Initialize Enzyme
import * as enzyme from 'enzyme';
import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

One of the tests (just changed the name of the components and props):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

it('test 1', () => {
    const elem = shallow(
        <Foo
            objId="id123"
            subject="subject"
            startTime={new Date(2018, 0, 1, 2, 30)}
            endTime={new Date(2018, 0, 1, 3, 45)} />
    );

    expect(elem.find('.foo').text()).toContain('subject');
});

it('test 2', () => {
    const elem = shallow(
        <Foo
            objId="id123"
            subject="subject"
            startTime={new Date(2018, 0, 1, 2, 30)}
            endTime={new Date(2018, 0, 1, 3, 45)} />
    );

    expect(elem.text()).toContain('foo');
});

it('test 3', () => {
    var today = new Date();
    today.setHours(2);
    today.setMinutes(30);

    const elem = shallow(
        <Foo
            objId="id123"
            subject="subject"
            startTime={today}
            endTime={today} />
    );

    expect(elem.find('.foo').text()).toContain(moment(today).format('dd/MM/yy'));
});

it('test 4', () => {
    var yesterday = new Date();
    yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1);
    yesterday.setHours(2);
    yesterday.setMinutes(30);

    const elem = shallow(
        <Foo
            objId="id123"
            subject="subject"
            startTime={yesterday}
            endTime={yesterday} />
    );

    expect(elem.find('.foo').text()).toContain(moment(yesterday).format('dd/MM/yy'));
});

it('test 5', () => {
    var lastWeek = new Date();
    lastWeek.setDate(lastWeek.getDate() - 7);
    lastWeek.setHours(2);
    lastWeek.setMinutes(30);

    const elem = shallow(
        <Foo
            objId="id123"
            subject="subject"
            startTime={lastWeek}
            endTime={lastWeek} />
    );

    expect(elem.find('.foo').text()).toContain(moment(lastWeek).format('dd/MM/yy'));
});

it('test 6', () => {
    var lastMonth = new Date();
    lastMonth.setDate(lastMonth.getDate() - 32);
    lastMonth.setHours(2);
    lastMonth.setMinutes(30);

    const elem = shallow(
        <Foo
            objId="id123"
            subject="subject"
            startTime={lastMonth}
            endTime={lastMonth} />
    );

    expect(elem.find('.foo').text()).toContain(moment(lastMonth).format('dd/MM/yy'));
});

it('test 7', () => {
    var start = new Date();
    start.setHours(2);
    start.setMinutes(30);

    var end = new Date();
    end.setHours(4);
    end.setMinutes(0);

    const elem = shallow(
        <Foo
            objId="id123"
            subject="subject"
            startTime={start}
            endTime={end} />
    );

    expect(elem.find('.foo').first().text()).toContain(moment(start).format('dd/MM/yy'));
    expect(elem.find('.foo').first().text()).toContain(moment(end).format('dd/MM/yy'))
});
```

Vesions:

```
"jest": "24.9.0"
"ts-jest": "24.0.2"
"enzyme": "3.7.0"
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.7.0"
```

Comment: Could it be that since you specified node_modules and <rootDir> it searches through node_modules twice thereby increasing your run time? Or considering using node as the testEnvironment?

Comment: Tried that, didn't help :(

Comment: So the tests are fast, but the files are slow: what else is happening during the test process? What else is happening in the app that might cause a delay?

Comment: Nothing. Each test dose shallow rendering and check for properties, clicks, etc. No more than that. I can add a test file if you want...
Just want to mention that after Jest cache the tests, they are running much faster. The problem that the CI is not caching anything...

Comment: That's potentially beneficial. Also it'd be good to understand if it's only component tests that tack on the extra eight minutes (e.g., the two components you show clearly cause a slowdown while the one below does not). Are you certain there's no async requests that are timing out somewhere?

Comment: I will add. The components test are much much slower than the "regular" tests. There are no async requests in the tests.

Comment: Not asking if there are any in the tests--I'm asking if there are any in the code, like the components, a reducer, etc. There's *something* chewing up time, and it's unlikely to be Jest itself, so it'd either doing more work than it needs to, or there's something running that's not in plain sight.

Comment: Seems like each individual test runs fast but the test file itself is slow, the bottleneck is either in the setup() or cleanup() for each test file. Could you give an example of the code in your setup?

Comment: Yes, I understand. These test are testing only the "view" component. Which have no complex logic inside - they take most of the time. Reducers are just update state (no async) and they also can take 29 sec as you see.

Comment: I didn't define the setup and cleanup... I've uploaded one of my tests

Comment: I've uploaded a test file that takes more than 400 secs... As you can see, it is very simple one... The `Foo` component, is a view component, which means that it have only `render` function inside without any complex logic, just simple rendering logic (if else, nothing more than that)

Comment: @DaveNewton is there a way to profile Jest test? Maybe it will reveal what is going on these tests...

Comment: The test by itself looks perfectly fine and no reason to take that long. Try getting rid of unnecessary jest configs and use the defaults?

Comment: These are the default configuration for Typescript that I took from Jest documentation somewhere. Do you have a specific configurations that you suggest to try?

Comment: module.exports = {
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
} .... this?

Comment: This is not working. I have an issue: `This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.`... And I don't have JS/JSX files in my source code

Comment: hmm, try using a preset? like from here : https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/

Comment: Thanks, maybe slight improvements, but the times are still really high

Comment: oh :( then I'm at a loss without being able to debug the whole project by myself. Please update if you do find the solution

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to profile Jest tests? So I can check what it taking most of the time?

Comment: None that are super popular as far as I am aware but you can take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html (profiles rendering and so on ) and https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-react-profiler

Comment: I did profiling jest by using node --inspect ./node_modules/.bin/jest and Chrome Dev Tools to start profiling. My issue is pretty much the same. There are 2 problems I'm facing with, the first one is ts-jest takes lot of time to finish transforming typescript code (try to use swc-node/jest instead), and the second issue is because each test import all modules and if we have kind of redundant import (import * as x from 'library') it will eat up lot of time too. hope that you could figure your issue with those comments

Answer (score 0):

Adding to jest config settings:

```
globals: {
 'ts-jest': {
   diagnostics: {
     ignoreCodes: [151001],
   },
   isolatedModules: true,
  },
},
```

helped me.